# Different shiftwidth in .html and .md files

Tags: vimrc

I use gvim8.1. My settings file contains these 2 lines: `set expandtab, set shiftwidth = 4`. I have a file 'html.vim' in '~\vimfiles\after\ftplugin\'. The file is listed below:

```
set expandtab
setlocal shiftwidth=2
setlocal tabstop=2
```

Unfortunately, this file changes shiftwidth option when I'm working with vimwiki files, which have a .md extension. I've checked this with `:verbose set shiftwidth?`

How do I change this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Markdown *filetype* is based on the HTML one, because some HTML elements are also allowed in Markdown. This has the side effect that your HTML filetype settings are applied to Markdown, too.

However, you can use the *after directory* for the Markdown filetype to override the settings. Even as the HTML customization also uses the after directory, as a subordinate filetype this should be sourced before the Markdown ones (you can verify with `:scriptnames`).

So, put the following into `~\vimfiles\after\ftplugin\markdown.vim`:

```
setlocal shiftwidth=4 tabstop=4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the option for .md filetypes upon opening the file like this.

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.md set shiftwidth = 4
```

Comment: [And the reason why Ingo's answer is the correct one](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/wiki/where_to_put_filetype_specific_stuff)